# Server & Desktop installation

Tags: installation

Is it possible to install Ubuntu server and Ubuntu desktop on one hard drive? I ask because I tried installing Ubuntu 13.04 Desktop on my Profile 6 and Ubuntu Server on my drive but, it replaced my Desktop. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to?

Personally I would have installed Ubuntu Server with a Desktop GUI.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

If you really want to go that route, then I would advise that you setup your partitions accordingly, and therefore have your different OS on different partitions.